# Is it possible to run multiple spark files with full resources of a cluster?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have a.py & b.py files.

**a.py** >> SparkConf( Set to Master ) Using all the resources of clusters & master

**b.py** >> SparkConf( Set to Local ) Using only resources of master

If I run both in parallel then scripts are running. But if I change the SparkConf to the below mentioned,

**a.py** >> SparkConf( Set to Master ) Using all the resources of clusters & master

**b.py** >> SparkConf( Set to Master ) Using all the resources of clusters & master

Then, One goes in running state another goes in waiting state as there are no resource available to allocate to the other script.

So is it possible to run both scripts in parallel for the second case?

Comment: Presumably spark standalone?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming Spark Stand Alone, from the manuals: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/spark-standalone.html#launching-spark-applications, YES IT IS:

The standalone cluster mode currently only supports a simple FIFO scheduler across applications. However, to allow multiple concurrent users, you can control the maximum number of resources each application will use. By default, it will acquire all cores in the cluster, which only makes sense if you just run one application at a time. You can cap the number of cores by setting spark.cores.max in your SparkConf. For example:

```
val conf = new SparkConf()
  .setMaster(...)
  .setAppName(...)
  .set("spark.cores.max", "10")
val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
```